# Are questions about speech-language pathology on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

Are questions about the professional practice of [Speech-Language Pathology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech-language_pathology) on-topic? Much of the practice area of such clinicians relates to skills that language learners care about (e.g. pronunciation, tone, semantics, literacy, etc.), but approaches them from the perspective of treating a person with a sickness rather than educating a learner. Obviously, questions asking for specific professional diagnosis or treatment (e.g. Why does my son have a lisp and what should we do?) are off-topic, but general questions about how various techniques used by speech-language pathologists might help a person to gain or improve language skills may be very interesting or even useful to the broader language learning community.